# WPF How to erase a DrawingVisual with RemoveVisualChild

Tags: wpf, drawing

Using WPF I'm drawing symbols in the "fast way" (Drawing rendered on DrawingVisuals, no Shapes). So... I can successfully draw them and get hit-tested with no problem.
But when trying to remove them, using RemoveVisualChild() plus RemoveLogicalChild(), there is no effect on the screen: No visual removing.

I'm implementing my own displaying canvas-alike object (overriding VisualChildrenCount, GetVisualChild, MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride).

For a while I believed it was a problem of refresh, but after invoking many methods (InvalidateMeasure, InvalidateArrange, InvalidateViual and UpdateLayout, plus a Dispatcher calling technique for post background-threading  execution) well... the supposedly erased objects are still there.

A curious thing is that new objects going to be drawn OVER these erased ones, are in fact rendered UNDER them!!

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED: It was my mistake (what a shame!)... A recursive symbol update, started at property setter level, was repainting the object.